# Background jobs, wait and cron

Tags: shell, cron

I have the following ksh script:

```
sqlplus usr1/pw1@DB1 @$DIR/a.sql $1 &
sqlplus usr2/pw2@DB2 @$DIR/b.sql $1 &
wait
echo "Done!"
```

Where $DIR is a variable with the absolute path where a.sql and b.sql are.

For some time, I've been running this script daily and it works fine.
The intentions is that both SQL*Plus sessions go to the background and
execute in parallel, and when they finish I can continue with the
following steps of the application.

Since it's not a test version anymore, I scheduled it on the crontab
to execute daily. The problem I have now is that it wont pause on
"wait" and let the sqlplus sessions finish, but it directly outputs
"Done!". In the real app, that "echo Done!" is actually a call to
another program to do some processing on a.sql's and b.sql's output.
But since it's not waiting for both sql scripts to actually finish,
the processing cannot be done.

It works absolutely perfect when I run it myself, wether I do it from
the local directory or from the root (as crontab would do it). But
when it is executed automatically by the crontab, I't doesn't stop at
wait and screws the whole thing up.

Any ideas on what might be happening? Thanks!

Comment: Add `PATH=/path/to/oracle/sqlplus:$PATH` at the top of your script, using off course, the real path to sqlplus. Also learn how to use `set -vx` to see what is being executed AND how to redirect output from your crontab entries into a /tmp file. You may find that output from your script (especially 'sqlpus, bad command or filename' is in your local mail file on the server where the crontab runs. `mail`. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter what makes you think that's the problem? im pretty sure the sqlplus is being executed becouse I can see the spooled files. I will try that tomorrow at work anyway. thanks for your help

Comment: based on your description, if there is nothing to wait for, the closing message will print right away. Why is there nothing to wait? The easiest guess is that your local cmdline environment has PATH with /path/to/oracle and your crontab'd script is not loading the same environment files, to set the correct PATH for sqlplus. Just a guess. Good luck!